# отнять число от переменной BUILD_NUMBER

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

В groovy есть переменная BUILD_NUMBER указывающая на счетчик билда pipeline. Для автоматического удаления предыдущего билда решил отнимать от BUILD_NUMBER единицу. Но как бы я не пробывал отнять Jenkins выдает ошибку на неправильный синтаксис. Можете привести пример создания переменной отличающейся от BUILD_NUMBER на единицу?

Comment: видимо следует начать с чтения текста ошибки.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: ошибка: неправильный синтаксис. Я не правильно выразился в вопросе.